# Ubuntu+bazaar, update openerp through command line

Tags: 12.04, updates, launchpad, bazaar

I have the following enviroment:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- OpenERP 7.0
- bazaar 2.5.1

In relation to a [bug found](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-addons/+bug/1073087) on the OperErp 7. There is a patch, some user already tested and it seems to work. I installed OpenErp7 following the useful tutorial on [www.theopensourcerer.com](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/12/how-to-install-openerp-7-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/). One of the steps is to download and install bazaar and the download the last branch of OpenERP:

```
bzr branch lp:openobject-server/7.0 server
bzr branch lp:openobject-addons/7.0 addons
bzr branch lp:openerp-web/7.0 web
```

I'm new using bazaar. Have read the manual and checked some samples. But I don't want to risk doing an update to try to correct the bug and mess up the installation. Could someone instruct me on the steps to do it? I mean, to download and install the patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands can be used:

```
bzr patch <patch_filename_or_url>
patch <patch_filename_or_url>
```

First one worked for me.